# setInexactRepeating of AlarmManager in not working for Android 12 and below

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I have a requirement to sync data back to API in every one 1 and for that I am using AlarmManager's SetInexactRepeating method. It is working fine and  invoking the method in every 1 minute but if I am running it on Android 10 or 11 then it is not repeating the call.

I tried using SetRpeating method also but again it is not working.

Here is code snippets I am using

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(BackgroundTaskReceiver));
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
 alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

 long triggerTime = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
 
     alarmManager.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, 60000, pendingIntent);
```

BackgroundTaskReceiver is class I have created by inheriting BroadcastReceiver and overridden it's OnReceive method and executing the code in this methiod.

On Documentation I have read that it works fine for older version of the android too but Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No log is coming. I just added the receiver in manifest file and starts  working but still few devices with Android 10/11 stops working after few minutes.

Comment: You can try to add [Diagnostics of AppCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/)  to your app. The App Center Diagnostics SDK collects information about crashes and errors in your apps and uploads them to the App Center portal for analysis by the development team.

Comment: Yes @JessieZhang-MSFT . We are using AppCenter for Crashlytics and error reporting and logging the exceptions to app center using TryCatch but no traces. Do you think there might be case or scenario where BraodcastReceiver may stop receiving event?  We have created a class and inherited it from BroadCastReceiver and overridden OnReceive method. Will there by any chance or case this OnReceive method will stop

Comment: Is your AlarmManager running in a service?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No, I am calling a method through broadcast receiver,

Comment: Could you please post more code snippets or share [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?